# How can I prepend a directory to PATH using RVM on a per project basis?

Tags: ruby, rvm

RVM supports `.ruby-version` and `.ruby-gemset` on a per project basis and ensures those are set correctly when you navigate to a directory containing those files.

Is there a similar construct I can use for adding directories to my environment `PATH` variable using RVM?

Comment: When discussing your environment, the variable name is `PATH`. When accessing its contents you use `$PATH`. So, you want to modify `PATH`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't found a way to do this using RVM, but I came across another project called [direnv](https://github.com/zimbatm/direnv) that accomplishes exactly what I want.

Here are the steps I took to prepend `./bin` to my environment PATH variable on OSX every time I go to my project directory in the shell:

1. `brew install direnv`
2. Add `eval "$(direnv hook $0)"` to the end of my `.zshrc` file.
3. Create a `.envrc` file in the root of my project with the following content:

   PATH_add bin